# Google Cloud Instance/VM in Zone failed to start due to low resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently encountering the issue seen in the picture below. For over three days, I'm not able to start the respective instance/vm as it says that there's not enough resources in the europe/zurich zone at the moment.

Does anyone have an idea, how long it takes Google Cloud to get these resources back?

Is anyone stuck with the same problem currently?

[image]

Comment: Select a different zone or a different instance size. Usually selecting a larger instance size works. However, sometimes a zone is just out of resources.

Comment: Thanks for your support! Do you know, how long it usually takes them to get resources available again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's [Resource availability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability), and there are some resolutions that show  on the link,

1. Switching zone, for instance,  `asia-south1-c` to  `asia-south1-a`
2. Try start again later.
3. Use Compute Engine reservations.

You may evaulate that stopping VM is better approach or keep that live, because there's [SUV](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts) for GCE resource.

Comment: Thanks for your support! Do you know, how long it usually takes them to get resources available again?

Comment: Sorry I don’t know that, even there is no resource to know that is available again.

Comment: No worries, appreciate your quick support! Changing from -a to -b seems to work. So, I'll wait until the resources in -a are available again. Thanks!